# Where are Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, plugins

Where do Firefox extensions (`.xpi` files) go when downloaded/installed?

I want to know the location (path) of extracted extension files.

I am using Firefox 33.1.1 binary (non-installer) version and want to load my extensions by simply moving the extracted `.xpi` files to the appropriate location to have them without installing separately every time (if that's possible).

Comment: In the firefox user profile directory

Comment: `%appdata%\mozilla\extensions` is empty but i have extension installed and working on my **non-installer** version of firefox

Comment: Yes; well that isn't the user profile if your using a portable edition of firefox

Comment: please read my post again, you must have omitted the third paragraph where i mentioned the version i'm using

Comment: Type about:plugins into the URL window and it will show the locations.  BTW, Mozilla has a support forum: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox that is a pretty good source.

Comment: thank you, but it lists *plugins* such as `shockwave flash`, i want to see the locations of installed *extensions* such as `stylish`

Comment: A tag question for you.  On this question, the distinction between plugins and extensions is important.  The [plugins] tag has a substantial question base.  [extension] & [.xpi] are both unique to this single question.  The purpose of the tags is to attract the people who follow the tag to get an answer.  I'm guessing [plugins] is the tag that interested people already follow, and [extension] & [.xpi] probably don't attract additional readers as extra tags.  Would you be amenable to dropping those two tags and letting them be deleted?  The edit will bump the question up in the active list.

Comment: I believe the directory structure is pretty similar between Windows and Linux once you get inside the mozilla directory.  On Linux, Stylish is not in mozilla/extensions; it is in mozilla/firefox/<profilename>/extensions.  If you click on Help | Troubleshooting Information in Firefox, you get a page that identifies a lot of detail.  There's an Extensions section, and Stylish is listed as having an ID that is a long alphanumeric string inside curly braces.  That ID is one of the items in this extensions directory.  Looks like that's the directory you need.